# Override focusVisible on MuiLink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to override the `focusVisible` property on all the (material ui) `Links` in my app.

I know that I can use

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  focus: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
}));
```

and then

```
const classes = useStyles();
// ...
<Link classes={{ focusVisible: classes.focus }}>{linkText}</Link>
```

within my component, however I don't want to have to remember to do this for every `Link` in my app.

I have tried using the `overrides` feature in `createMuiTheme`:

```
const myNewTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiLink: {
      focusVisible: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

but it doesn't seem to be picking this value up.

What do I need to do to globally apply my chosen `focusVisible` styling to all `Links` in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`focusVisible` is available as utility className which has no reference selector. It should work using the following global override:

```
const myNewTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiLink: {
      root: {
        '&.Mui-focusVisible': {
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```